# How to dynamically set id of <TD> when creating HTML table via iteration and then get ID value onBlur action?

Tags: javascript, onblur

I am trying to dynamically create an HTML table by iterating through an array, and on each iteration, set the id of a particular cell with the value of i, from the stepper variable in the for loop. I then want to be able to access the cells ID following an onBlur event.

This is what I have tried:

```
        function saveToDB(id) {
            document.write(id);
        }
        
        function makeEditTableHTML(studentArray) {
                var result = "<table id='dataEditTableid' class='stripe' border=1><thead><tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>Student Email</b></td><td><b>Target</b></td></tr></thead>";
                result += "<tbody>";
                for(var i=0; i<studentArray.length; i++) {
                    result += "<tr>";
                    result += "<td>"+studentArray[i][1]+"</td>";
                    result += "<td>"+studentArray[i][0]+"</td>";
                    result += "<td id=i contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDB(this.id)'></td>";
                    result += "</tr>";
                }
                result += "</tbody></table>";

                return result;
            }
```

The `document.write` is just for testing purposes, but it consistently outputs the letter `i` regardless of the cell being edited.

How can I program it so that the active cell's id value is passed into the saveToDB function, when the onBlur event occurs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The entire way you're doing this loop needs to be rewritten.  By concatenating data directly into HTML, you're opening yourself up to various attacks, as well as just broken HTML.  You need to escape your text content for use in HTML.  The easiest way to do that is to simply set the `textContent` of elements.  A better way is to use a JavaScript-based template engine so this is done for you.  Also, don't set an event handler on every cell.  Use a single handler on the table itself and check the event's target's dataset.  Use `data-id=...` rather than `id=...` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hard-coding the letter `i` into the cell. You need to concatenate it, so:

```
"<td id=i contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDB(this.id)'></td>";
```

needs to be:

```
"<td id=" + i + " contenteditable='true' onBlur='saveToDB(this.id)'></td>";
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately the document.write is now outputting + i + as opposed to the id number?

Comment: OK, please accept my apology, I used single quotes not double. Using double does display a numerical value. Thank you ever so much

Comment: @sw123456 You're welcome. Please consider marking this as "the" answerr by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the aswer.

Comment: Hi, I was going to, I just needed to wait a couple of minutes before it let me. All done now. Thanks again!